# Cannot focus on element in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm new to automation test in Selenium. I was assigned to run the test on Microsoft Edge browser. Everything was ok until I run the test. It stops every single time it reaches this line:

```
clickElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'cleditorMain')]")));
```

The program doesn't crash. It just stops there without any error or exception. Initially I guessed it was caused by the wrong xpath but when I tried to run the test on other browsers like Chrome or IE, it passed.

*The following elements can still be focused:

```
clickElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mCSB_1_container']/ul/li[2]/a")));
      clickElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li/i")));

clickElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'サブG99-00')]")));

   clickElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[contains(@id,'_mainc')]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a")));
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: Maybe By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'cleditorMain')]")) finds several elements?

Comment: @Stefan No it only finds 1 matching element.

Comment: @AnhPhan61 You need to improve your code with Relative xpath instead of Dynamic xpath.

Comment: Use webdriver timeouts. Check if this element is inside a iframe on Edge. And verify the xpath against Edge. Also you can try with building an action that move to it and clicks.

Comment: What do you have your implicit wait set to?  Since you say it appears to just wait and do nothing (hang) it's possible that you have a very high implicit wait set.  What is the element (tag) that you actually want to click?  Try changing the asterisk to that tag name.